# Setting Order in the properties of a class

Tags: c#

I have a class with 10 properties and I am using reflection to assign values to these properties. My Property names are like,

```
            private double? _col1;
    public double? Col1
    {
        get
        {
            return _col1;
        }
        set
        {
            _col1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Col1");
        }
    }

    private double? _col2;
    public double? Col2
    {
        get
        {
            return _col2;
        }
        set
        {
            _col2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Col2");
        }
    }
```

And I am using them like,

```
        MyClass md = new MyClass();
       
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
         {
             foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                        {
                            double? d1 = from some method();

                            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Double?))
                            {
                                if (property.GetValue(md) == null)
                                {
                                    property.SetValue(md, d1);                                        
                                }
                            }
                        }

         }
```

Here I want to use an orderby property name of the class. How ??

```
               PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
```

Comment: Why do you care about the order? And why are you doing all this via reflection? This seems like an XY problem to me, what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Appending a custom `.OrderBy()` to the result of `GetProperties()` sounds like a potential way to order the results...

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort `properties` alphabetically based on their name.

Add the following line before the `foreach()` loop

```
Array.Sort(properties, (x,y)=> x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name)
```

Comment: We almost never use `Array.Sort` any more, it's much better to use Linq `OrderBy`.

Comment: @DavidG - why so? I see internally `Array.Sort()` is implemented with unmanaged code (C++), and `.OrderBy()`  uses a managed `QuickSort()` algorithm. Can't tell why one would be better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Order of properties in reflection is the same as in their declaration in program code. Property declared first is first. Property declared second is second. I have never tested myself, but in case of partial classes, when a class is split into several files, the situation might be tricky.

> how **we can ensure** that it takes first Col1, then secondly Col2, etc ??

**To ensure**, You should use names of the properties. Example

```
if (property.Name == nameof(MyClass.Col1))
{
    property.SetValue(instanceOfClassName, value);
}
```

Alternative for `if` is `switch` statement

```
switch (property.Name)
{
    case nameof(MyClass.Col1):
        break;
    case nameof(MyClass.Col2):
        break;
}
```

If you want to order the properties by name then simply use `OrderBy` LINQ query

```
var orderedByNameProperties = properties.OrderBy(property => property.Name);
```

Comment: i edited the question, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an XY problem.

I think what you actually need could be something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<double?> Cols { get; }

    public MyClass(int initialSize)
    {
        if(initialSize < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(initialSize));
        }

        Cols = new(Enumerable.Repeat((double?)null, initialSize));
    }
}
```

Then, ditching the reflection, you can just use a for loop on the observable collection. The observable collection is great cause it already raises events informing about changes.

```
MyClass md = new MyClass(2);

for (int i = 0; i < md.Cols.Count; i++)
{
    double? d1 = from some method();

    if (md.Cols[i] is null)
    {
        md.Cols[i] = d1;
    }
}
```

Then, if someone needs to listen to changes made to `Cols`, they subscribe to the `Cols.CollectionChanged` event.

Comment: Please check the question. I edited it